# jQuery ajax in ASP.NET with customErrors mode="On"

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

any idea how to retrieve the original exception thrown on server side when doing
ajax calls with jQuery  and using

> customErrors mode="On"

in web.config.

If mode="Off" I can take the error using this function:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var error = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); 
        alert(error.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to move the server method into a different host with its own `web.config`. If you've never done this before, [ASP.NET Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx) is a good place to start.

If that's not practical, you could wrap the entire server method in a `try ... catch` and modify the method so that its *successful* return values include exception information. That has a few drawbacks: you'd have to modify the `$.ajax` `success` handler to check for errors manually, and you'd only capture exceptions that occur in the server method (but you'd miss http timeouts, DNS resolution errors, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a couple of differens solutions:

Either, you could disable customerrors for a specific location in web.config.

```
<location path="ajaxReuests">
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
</location>
```

However, be aware of the customerrors [security vunerability](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/18/important-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx) when disabling custom errors.

Another (safer solution) would be to use the ajax-complete-callback-handler together with meta tags on the error pages to detect errors and forward the response to the "normal" error function. In order for this to work, you need to include the error status code on your custom error pages, eg:

```
<head runat="server">
  <title>Oops</title>
  <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta name="statuscode" content="500" />
  ...
```

Then you could parse out the status code from XmlHttpRequest.responsText and invoke the normal error function if an errorneous status code is detected.

```
$.ajax({

  url: '/ajax/mydata.ashx',
  dataType: 'json',

  complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
    var statuscodeRegex = /content="(.*?)"/;
    if (statuscodeRegex.test(XMLHttpRequest.responseText) &&
      statuscodeRegex.exec(XMLHttpRequest.responseText)[0] != 200)
      this.error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, "Oh no... an error!");
  },

  success: function(myData) {
    //Do something useful...
  },

  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //Error...
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh, I see not that I probably did not answer your question entirely. if you want the entire excepton from the server, you cannot use the second approach. You could of course include the server exception (eg printing Server.GetLastError() in a div) on the custom error page and get it by parsing  the responseText property in the complete-handler (similar to what I did with the status code), but that would reveal the exception to everyone.